# In Python3.5:NameError: name 'image_to_string' is not defined

Tags: python, pytesser

I have tried to print pytesser,it told me that name 'pytesser' is not defined.I have import pytesser,but I don't know why It hasn't defined?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your source code so we can look over the code and get more details. Also your error is caused by a variable declaration without a definition following. Check for any stand alone variable's that have no following "= ...definition".